# Is it possible to have Global Modal Input using Input Method Engine?

Tags: input, emacs, i3, fcitx

**Prelude:** *Part-1:*

I have pain in my little fingers and wrists if I have to repeatedly press key combinations such as `Ctrl+Shift+<key>`.

I found some respite in using `vi`'s modal editing which largely eliminated the need for such key combinations. More recently I have been using the `God-mode` in `Emacs` and it also works great. Here is a short description of `God-mode` (adapted from their github page):

[God-mode](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/god-mode) is an global minor mode for entering `Emacs` commands without modifier keys. For example in this mode one can do the following:

```
Before: C-p C-k C-n M-^ ) C-j C-y M-r C-x z z M-2 M-f C-x C-s
After:    p   k   n g ^ )   j   y g r     . .   2 g f   x   s
```

(You may check out their [key-mapping section](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/god-mode#key-mapping) for an explanation of the framework).

So far so good! However a lot of applications (outside of the nice `Emacs` and `vi`/`vim` world) require me to press key combinations such as `Ctrl+Shift+Tab` or `Ctrl+Alt+u` etc, which are hurting my wrists and little fingers.

**Prelude:** *Part-2:*

I am aware of the [Input Method framework/ Input Method Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_input_methods_for_Unix_platforms) that allows users to enter foreign characters and glyphs with key combinations. Here is an [Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lJoXhS4EUJs) demonstrating the use of [fctix5](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fcitx5) to input Japanese characters/ glyphs.

I am also aware of [Plover](http://www.openstenoproject.org/plover/) project from the [Open Steno Project](http://www.openstenoproject.org/) which is an open-source stenography engine, that can translate *key-chords* on an *N-key rollover-keyboard* into English words via a predefined dictionary. I also know that `Plover` supports modifier keys such as `Ctrl`, `Alt`, `Shift` etc.

**Questions:**

I wish to have an `Emacs's God-mode` like framework system wide everywhere that works across applications, so that I wouldn't ever have to press `Ctrl+Shift+<key>` and instead I can simply press `G <Key>` etc.

1. Does there already exist something like this?
2. If no, will it be possible to build something like this? I am thinking of a `Plover` like daemon that would translate `G <key>` to `Ctrl+Shift+<key>` etc.
3. Will `Plover` qualify as an `Input Method Engine` (in the same sense that `fcitx5` is an `Input Method Engine`)? If no, how are `Plover` and `fcitx` different?
4. I use `i3` as my window manager. I would want that my Global Modal Input translator should intercept and process my keybindings before my window manager does. Will that be possible?

Comment: I know nothing of "Input Method Engine" but perhaps "sticky modifier keys" would help?  You configure that in your OS, and then you never have to hold a modifier for any application.  I have it so a single tap modifies the subsequent key, and a double-tap locks the modifier on until the next time I tap it.  So you never need to hold a modifier, and you get the equivalent of Caps Lock for *all* modifiers, rather than just shift (obviously rendering Caps Lock itself redundant, so you can use that key for something else).  IIRC I think "Ctrl Lock" would be similar to `god-mode`?

Comment: @phils: Indeed that is a great suggestion and a great starting place. Thanks!

Comment: I intend to take it a few steps further from Phil's idea. I have started this [github issue](https://github.com/emacsorphanage/god-mode/issues/140) where I intend to extend `god-mode` system wide and outside of Emacs! I will post updates here if any concrete progress is made.